the withObservables's callback props is empty in watermelondb
im trying to use watermelondb observable feature but for some reason the callback props from the withObservables is empty. Im using react-native with expo sdk 51, in android
const enhance = withObservables(['users'], (e) => {
  console.log(e); // it is empty {}

  return {
    users: database.get('users').query().observe()
  };
});

export const EnhancedUsers = enhance(ListUsers);


the only way i fond to have it working is by using this code with the compose function but, i don't find any documentation about how to type it(i am using typescript). any ideia of how to do it?. If possible i would rather to use withObservables.
const EnhancedUsers = compose(
  withDatabase,
  withObservables(['users'], (e) => {
    return {
      user: e.database.get('users').query().observe()
    };
  })
)(ListAllUsers);
const EnhancedUsers = enhance(ListAllUsers);


